# Air handler blower, motor, or something else?

Tags: hvac

My blower just stopped working. I have 240 volts to the motor but it won't spin. It will turn an inch or so but that's it and it tries repeatedly. Could it be something besides the blower or the motor? It's a variable speed.

Comment: Kill the power. Can you spin the fan? Take the belt loose, can you spin the motor easily? If everything spins OK, it could be the run capacitor.

Comment: It's a direct drive; no fan. It sounds by hand easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ECM Motor Troubleshooting* –[yorkcentraltechtalk](https://yorkcentraltechtalk.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/ecm-motor-troubleshooting-part-1/)

> Troubleshooting the ECM motor can be very simple if you just remember that it's not just ON or OFF.  There are basically 4 problems that will not allow the motor to run:

- There is no input power to the motor controller (high voltage input).
- There is improper or no communication to the motor (low voltage inputs). This problem could be the CFM Programming control or board or the low voltage connector (wiring harness).
- The motor controller (module) has failed.
- The motor has failed (least likely of all the problems)

Comment: I've never had to diagnose an ECM yet. HTH

Comment: I'm an engineer and an avid diyer; full disclosure.

Comment: High voltage check. Control board looks good; lights and components not blown, fan light on, CFM light flickering. Motor controller?  The board I just spoke of?  The schematic only shows the group of low voltage wires from the board to the connector, but no definitions.

Comment: The dude in [this video has some specific diagnostic equipment for ECMs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_LQSqgKR8E) that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: @EvilElf - You'll need someone else to help you with those schematics; end of my rope here.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The ECM module is fine. The motor fails the phase resistance test. New one is $1200 from Trane. I found a used one on eBay for $200.

Comment: I'm curious to know what could have caused the motor windings to short.