# ECM motor in air handler not reaching full speed

Tags: hvac, heat-pump

I replaced the motor back in this thread at the height of the summer heat: [old question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/92817/2271)

The old motor was fine as I opened it up and a bug got fried inside and caused a short. I ended up with a backup motor.

The new motor just started to spin at a lower speed, thus causing heat exchange issues with the heat pump. The board looks physically fine. The other motor spins in a cycle when hooked up, but not installed into the squirrel cage. I believe it is doing the torque check upon getting the startup signal but never goes full speed in one direction.  I think I remember it spinning at full speed when I tested it during the previous repair, outside the cage.

Do I need to install the motor into the squirrel cage to confirm it is the control board or can I assume the control board is the culprit?